# Can my original 2005 Xbox 360 Media Remote control my TV?

Tags: xbox-360

I found an Xbox 360 Media Remote ("minimote") that came with the first batch of original Xbox 360s back when the dinosaurs were alive (c. 2005). It looks like it was designed as a DVD/video remote. I know the new media remotes and universal controllers can both control the television (turn it off/on, change volume), but can this older version be programmed to do this too? I found "TV codes" online for the original remote, but no instructions on how to get the remote to pair with the 360 or the TV. Is this remote even capable of turning the television off (or any other interaction with the television) and how can I set it up?

It's the *little one on the left* (just not in Japanese):

[image: 360 remote, WP Commons, Tsukihito, cc-by-sa-3.0]

<sub>**Image:** [WP Commons, Tsukihito, cc-by-sa-3.0](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Xbox_360_Media_Remote_and_Universal_Media_Remote.jpg)</sub>

Comment: This is an assumption on my part, but I don't think you are going to be able to make it work. As it would likely need the number buttons. Also, it seems like google/Internet would know the answer to this. Look for a model number or product ID on the remote, and add that to your Internet recon.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use the original short remote to control the TV. There are no mentions around the Internet of using this original remote to control TVs, and the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_360_accessories#Universal_Media_Remote) description of the original remote and its longer replacement describes controlling TVs as being a feature introduced by the longer version (emphasis mine):

> There are two official versions of Remote control for the Xbox 360 […] The first official media remote is the **shorter version of the Universal Media Remote** that can be bought at retail. It was supplied at launch with the Premium version of the console […] These were sold in limited quantities. All remotes can assist in the playing of DVD movies and music […], **while the Universal Media Remote offers more function by having the ability to serve as a control for a number of TVs** or Windows Media Center-based PC.

The article goes on to describe the *new* short remote (the black glossy one), so it's pretty clear that the short "Universal" non-TV one mentioned in that snippet is the same one you've got.

Comment: The "mini" remote clearly based on the controlls it does have is a modified xbox controller in the form of a remote.  The longer one has the typical channel controls plus those same controls.

Answer (score -1):

I have one of these and there's no way to use it with a TV.